# Types of font (Black, Thin, ecta) not installing (22.04)

Tags: fonts, 22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm trying to install some fonts (Albertus Nova), and Regular, Bold, and Light installed fine, but Black and Thin didn't install.
Here are a couple of fonts that have problems:

- Shag Lounge
- Albertus Nova (Black, Thin)

When I try to install them, they just go green again. Is there some way to hack the app so it works?

Comment: Colour is not a property of a font. Some font variations that are called "Black" are thicker than their regular versions, but are not automatically coloured black.

Comment: What I mean by "they just go green again", I meant it goes from the gray "Installing" to the green "Install", which probably means it failed. It installed properly on Windows 10 though.